# Need a specific row in between another row in SQL

Tags: sql

I have this table `Organisation`:

| ID | Resource |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Software Engineer |
| 2 | Tech Lead |
| 3 | Architect |
| 4 | Senior Software Engineer |
| 5 | HR |

I need to fetch this table using select query such that the output which I receive should have ID 4 between ID 1 and ID 2

Output:

| ID | Resource |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Software Engineer |
| 2 | Tech Lead |
| 4 | Senior Software Engineer |
| 3 | Architect |
| 5 | HR |

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `should have ID 4 between ID 1 and ID 2` ... but that's not what your data shows, which has ID 4 between 2 and 3.

Comment: oracle or mysql? please remove unrelated tags!

Comment: Use `case` expressions and remap anything you wand to numbers. Then use `order by`

Comment: @harish, when you post a question here, it's a great idea to hang around for a while and answer the comments you get. Otherwise lack of clarity will perhaps get your question closed before it has an accurate answer.

Comment: @jarlh i was in other work till now and just checked responses.Will update accordingly thank you

Comment: Implementing logic depending on hard-coded values usually means your overall design could be improved.

Comment: Perhaps adding a `sort` column to your table would be a better idea than hardcoding ids into your query?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to retrieve specific rows from your Organization table based on the ID. To achieve this, you can use the ORDER BY clause along with a CASE statement in your SQL query. Here's your query:

```
    SELECT ID, Resource
    FROM Organization
    ORDER BY 
      CASE 
        WHEN ID = 4 THEN 1
        ELSE ID 
      END;
```

This query will prioritize the row with ID 4 to be placed after ID 1. The rest of the rows will be ordered based on their IDs.

Comment: Thanks for your response.Can i use this query by using Resource column rather than ID?

Comment: @harish Try this

`SELECT ID, Resource
FROM Organization
ORDER BY 
  CASE Resource
    WHEN 'Software Engineer' THEN 1
    WHEN 'Senior Software Engineer' THEN 2
    WHEN 'Tech Lead' THEN 3
    ELSE 4 
  END;`

Comment: If there are 15 entries then the query would become to long right

Comment: Will put 4 and 1 in the same position, more or less randomly sorted.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `CASE` expression to generate the ordering you want:

```sql
SELECT ID, Resource
FROM Organisation
ORDER BY CASE ID WHEN 4 THEN 1.5 ELSE ID END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `SELECT` query with an `ORDER BY` clause to specify the order in which the rows should be displayed.

```
SELECT ID, Resource
FROM Organisation
ORDER BY
  CASE
    WHEN ID = 4 THEN 1
    WHEN ID BETWEEN 1 AND 2 THEN 0
    ELSE 2
  END,
  ID;
```